# How to retrieve data from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-server

Using the parse how to retrieve the data to the table view controller if multiple objects are present.

I tried using the query where receptionist equal to current user.

And I tried find objects in background and append it to an array.

But the problem is all the object values appending to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the Parse IOS Developer's Guide. It has the information & explanations you need to do this.

http://parseplatform.org/docs/ios/guide/

Also, what you're asking really isn't too clear. Try to specify what specific issues you are having along with posting your actual code next time.